# Executing Chrome content script after AJAX request that has been fired from <body> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, google-chrome-extension

I am having difficulties running content script before DOM has loaded. There is an AJAX request in  tag which is fired on $(document).ready(), when the request has completed I run my extension code.

I am observing that request through webRequest API on background.js, like so:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(details.url.indexOf("ajax.php") != -1) {
                // sending message to tab where the AJAX request fired from
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, message);
        }
    },
    {urls: ["*://derp.com/*""]}
);
```

And then I am waiting for the message to be received on content script .

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(msg.action == "onInventoryLoaded") {
        epicStuff();
    }
});
```

But the message most of the time is not received on content script because it has not been run yet, even if I have instructed Chrome to run the content script on document_start.

```
{
    "matches": [
        "http://derp.com/*"
    ],
    "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
    ],
    "run-at": "document_start"
}
```

What really bothers me is how Tampermonkey extension is able to run user-script much earlier than Chrome extension (figured that out through logging timestamps).

I also sent extension to someone else to try and the content script was running before the AJAX request. So I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: If it really is "run-at" that you've put in your manifest, it should be "run_at".

Comment: @kalman wow.. I feel so stupid now, you're right. Feel free to post answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @kalman, I had wrong property in manifest.json file, it is supposed to be run_at and not run-at. Sucks that Chrome does not point out wrong/invalid property names.